Solving synthetic geometry

$D$ is a point inside $\triangle ABC$ such that $\angle DAC=\angle DBC$. From $D$ two perpendicular lines are drawn on $AC, BC$ which intersect $AC, BC$ in $P, Q$ points respectively. $O $is the midpoint of $AB$. Then prove that $OP=OQ$

I have found out that $P,D,Q,C$ are concylic. Let $AD$ and $BD$ intersect $BC$ and $AC$ at $F$ and $E$ respectively. Then I also have found out that $A,B,E,F$ are concyclic. But I cannot find a way to prove angle $OPQ = \angle OQP$

An image says more than a thousand words :-) :-) :-)

Why should this question be closed ? The asker has worked on his/her question !

What happened ? What rules did I violate ? Please let me know ! I am new in this website

It is actually a cool geometry problem, why is it closed?

Couldn't there exist a proof using transformations ?

I just realised that this question is practically the same as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155621/inscribed-quadrilateral

@JeanMarie if you mean a proof using spiral similarity, if you go to the other question I linked, there is one solution proving that the line passes through the midpoint and is perpendicular to prove it is the perpendicular bisector. The fact that it passes through the midpoint may be proven considering the Miquel point of ABCD.

@Antonio Thanks for the informations in your comment. Indeed, this answer gives an alternative solution. I have erased it provisionally because there is a big flaw in it.


Synthetic solution:
Let $T=AD\cap BC$, $S=BD\cap AC$. Let $E$ and $F$ be the intersections of the circle with diameter $AB$ (and center $O$) with $AC$ and $BC$ respectively.
We have $\angle EBS= \angle EBD= \angle EBC- \angle DBC= \angle FAC-\angle DAC=\angle FAD= \angle FAT$ where we used the given angle condition and the fact that $ABFE$ is cyclic. Because we also have $\angle SPD=\angle SEB=\angle TFA=\angle DQT= 90^{\circ}$ we get $\triangle SPD\sim \triangle SEB\sim \triangle TFA\sim \triangle TQD$ and so by Thales's proportionality theorem and similarity of triangles we get $$\frac{PE}{BD}=\frac{SP}{SD
}=\frac{TQ}{TD}=\frac{QF}{DA}$$
This means $$\frac{AP}{BQ}=\frac{AD}{BD}=\frac{QF}{PE} \implies PE\cdot PA=QF\cdot QB$$
If we denote the circle $(ABFE)$ by $\omega$, then P and Q have equal powers with respect to $\omega$ and so their distances to the center must be equal, i.e. $$PO=QO$$.

[+1] Please see my solution.
